# Multiple reset passwords in django

Tags: django, templates, url, passwords, reset

I have a project which have a personal app, where the login takes place, and a question app which also includes a profile page. I have managed to reset pasword from the login page, but when I try to do the same in the question app (using different templates, because I do not want the same on these pages), it just goes directly to the login reset template.

I thought it would be enough to just add a new registration folder in the questions app, but it still goes searching in the personal app I think.

Is it possible to just fix this using the django auth views or do I have to create my own views for the questions app?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create separate views, as well as separate templates.

First, make sure that you understand the User model, and how authentication works in Django.  The core docs have plenty of information on that.

Second, look at what you are trying to do and create a view specifically for the template you are creating.  Make sure that view processes the data the way that you want to, and that it redirects where you want the user to be redirected to after making the update.

One question to ask yourself though, before you go through this trouble is "Do I really need to have two places to do this?"

Having more than one location to handle password resets is not likely to end up being what you actually want in the long run.  I would personally keep all of the account manipulation views in one place so that you don't mess something up if you decide to change something in one place and forget in another.

Two principles that are important when developing any kind of site are KISS and DRY.  KISS is just the traditional keep it simple.

DRY means don't repeat yourself.

Unless there is a NEED to have the code be in two different places, it is a bad idea.  ESPECIALLY with account related things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's what I thought, the problem is though that I want to redirect to two different places. For example if you have forgot your password on the login site you will be able to login afterwards, but if you reset your password from your profile page you will just be directed to your profile page afterwards..

Comment: So, yes, you will want to create your own view or views and call one from the login screen and the other from the profile screen.  Make sure to use the methods provided but auth to actually make the change.  Also take whatever security precautions you feel comfortable with, such as asking for the current password to verify (on the profile screen version of course).